# Add-on SDK error when using var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

i'm a starter in javascript and is trying my hand in making an Add-on.To make a simple Add-on i use the following code in the tutorial.

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
   onClick: handleClick
 });

 function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("https://www.mozilla.org/");
}
```

This works perfectly. But in the next tutorial the code used includes

```
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

var button = ActionButton({
    id: "my-button",
     label: "my button",
    icon: {
      "16": "./firefox-16.png",
      "32": "./firefox-32.png"
    },
     onClick: function(state) {
         console.log("button '" + state.label + "' was clicked");
    }
   });
```

Here i'm getting a syntax error in the first line.When i tried to use the second code with var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action'); i'm getting no output. What am i doing wrong here>

Comment: what is the syntax error you are getting with first line ?

Comment: This is js 1.7 feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29 hope your testing it in browser supporting this version.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem in any recent version of Firefox. Are you getting the syntax error form Firefox or your editor?

Comment: @canuckistani i'm using dreamweaver and it's showing the syntax error. Browser shows nothing. i Use version 29 of firefox

Comment: Ignore dreamweaver - that syntax is *future* JavaScript that currently only works in Firefox and maybe Chrome, and that DW doesn't know about yet. See this post for more info: http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/50/